# Windows Phone 7 SQL Server CE rowversion

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I had a problem when updating a table in SQL Server CE on Windows Phone 7.  When I would call submit changes the app would close without any exceptions or errors. Visual Studio even remained running.

Removing the `rowversion` column fixed the problem. I've looked around and not sure if I'm missing something but is there anything special one needs to do when using a `rowversion` column?

Here are the attributes for the column. I created a simple table when trying to figure this out. It has 3 columns:

- `Id` (Guid)
- `TestColumn` (nvarchar100)
- `MyRowVersion` (rowversion)

Code:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_MyRowVersion", AutoSync=AutoSync.Always, DbType="rowversion", CanBeNull=true, IsDbGenerated=true, IsVersion=true, UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
```

Comment: I cannot repro with a nullable rowversion column, can you share your create table script?

Comment: Thanks Erik, in trying to re-create in a separate solution rowversion is working.  I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't' work in the other solution.

Comment: I read your new article and went to add a rowversion back in to my db and I can still crash it on a simple update with db.SubmitChanges().  I can get it to work in a test app.  I wonder if it has to do with the process running in a background task with async ctp, strange.

Comment: Assuming you generate the datacontext with the Toolbox, there is a bug, if you have indexes that cover the primary keys that causes the crash. Try to re-gen the DataContext with the latest Toolbox addin (version 2.6.2) and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes I'm using the toolbox to gen the context.  I'll check and try this when I get back and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: New version fixed the problem, nice being able to have toolbox add roversions to all tables.  Make an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you generate the datacontext with the SQL Server Compact Toolbox, there is a bug, if you have indexes that cover same columns as primary keys, that causes the crash. Try to re-gen the DataContext with the latest Toolbox addin (version 2.6.2 or later). Workaround for the issue is to delete the "duplicate" index.