# Strange SQL CE Finalize Error occuring on WP7 Application

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, windows-phone-7.1, finalizer

```
Frame    Image             Function                                                           Offset    
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                                 19        
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       436488    
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       386545    
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       540936    
4                          TransitionStub                                                     0         
5                          System.Data.SqlServerCe.ConStringUtil.ReplaceDataDirectory         0         
6                          System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.RemoveCachedMemoryUsage    64        
7                          System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ReleaseNativeInterfaces    488       
8                          System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Dispose                    372       
9                          System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Finalize                   64        
10       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       429164    
11       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       143533    
12       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       143225    
13       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       236605    
14       mscoree3_7.dll                                                                       305995    
15       coredll.dll       ThreadBaseFunc                                                     144
```

All calls to the SQL CE db are wrapped in Usings to ensure the object disposes properly.  I've found nothing on the web that exlains what is happening.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Curious, are you using rowversion?  Probably not related at all bu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622896/windows-phone-7-sqlce-rowversion

Comment: Nope - definitely not.  Using it in a very basic way to store data locally so that I can populate the app with data so it works offline.